Left Join on Data table with Where Clause using LinQ
I am trying to perform a left join on two data tables using LinQ and there are two WHERE Clause in it. Here is a snippet of the code:
I have tried the below code snippet:
var resultList = (from p in mainlineQuery1.AsEnumerable()
                              join t in mainlineQuery4.AsEnumerable()//.Where(x => x.Field<string>("mainlineidc") == null)
                              on p.Field<string>("globalid") equals t.Field<string>("featureguid")                              
                              into tempJoin
                              from temp in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where p.Field<string>("circuitid2") != null && temp.Field<string>("mainlineidc") == null
                              select new
                              {
                                  featClass = p.Field<string>("FeatureClass"),
                                  globalId = p.Field<string>("globalid"),
                                  circuitId = p.Field<string>("circuitid"),
                                  circuitId2 = p.Field<string>("circuitid2"),
                                  subtypecd = Convert.ToString(p.Field<decimal>("subtypecd")),
                                  operatingnumber = p.Field<string>("operatingnumber") //== string.Empty ? string.Empty : temp.Field<string>("mainlineidc")
                              }).ToList();

The number of records is not matching with the SQL Developer records.
Any help would be much appreciated!!

The problem was that your query referred to mainlineidc without defining it. Your
mainlineidc= temp == null ? null: temp.Field<string>("mainlineidc")

in the temp definition modifies the result set of the subquery so it will have a field of mainlineidc from now on, so you are no longer referring to undefined fields.

Thank you so much for your valuable input.

Got it fixed by changing the code to :
var resultList = (from p in mainlineQuery1.AsEnumerable()
                              join t in mainlineQuery4.AsEnumerable()
                              on p.Field<string>("globalid") equals t.Field<string>("featureguid")                              
                              into tempJoin
                              from temp in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where p.Field<string>("circuitid2") != null 
                              select new
                              {
                                  featClass = p.Field<string>("FeatureClass"),
                                  globalId = p.Field<string>("globalid"),
                                  circuitId = p.Field<string>("circuitid"),
                                  circuitId2 = p.Field<string>("circuitid2"),
                                  subtypecd = Convert.ToString(p.Field<decimal>("subtypecd")),
                                  operatingnumber = p.Field<string>("operatingnumber"),
                                  mainlineidc= temp == null ? null: temp.Field<string>("mainlineidc")
                              }).Where(x=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.mainlineidc)).ToList();

